# Showing that $\sqrt[3]{2}\notin\Bbb Q(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_k)$ where $\alpha_i^2\in\Bbb Q\ \forall i$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finitely-generated

Let $F$ be the field $\Bbb Q(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_k)$ where  $\alpha_i^2\in\Bbb Q\ \forall i$

I want to show that $\sqrt[3]{2}\notin F$

I thought if $\sqrt[3]{2}\in F$ then $\sqrt[3]{2}\in\Bbb Q\cup(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_k)$ but this is not a disjoint union so I'm not sure what to do... taking the square of $\beta:=\sqrt[3]{2}$ gives $2^{2/3}=\sqrt[3]{4}\notin\Bbb Q$ but that doesn't really advance things

So I'm looking for a hint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ has degree $3$ over $\Bbb{Q}$, but the other field $K$ has degree $2^l$ for some $l$. Hence $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})\subseteq K$ is impossible by the degree theorem. Hence $\sqrt[3]{2}\not\in K$.

Comment: How do you calculate the degree for $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$?

Comment: Its minimal polynomial is $x^3-2$, so the degree is $3$. For some details see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263289/elements-of-mathbb-q21-3).